# SQL Server Complex DateDiff Where Scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

This is the current table I am dealing with. I would like to record the length of time that the stations (st) are in state 5.

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+
| st1 | st2 | st3 | st4 | TimeStamp           |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+
| 3   | 3   | 3   | 3   | 2018-07-23 07:51:06 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+
| 5   | 5   | 5   | 5   | 2018-07-23 07:50:00 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+
| 0   | 0   | 10  | 10  | 2018-07-23 07:47:19 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+
| 5   | 5   | 5   | 5   | 2018-07-23 07:39:07 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+
| 3   | 3   | 10  | 10  | 2018-07-23 07:37:48 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+
| 3   | 3   | 10  | 10  | 2018-07-23 07:37:16 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+
```

This is about what I would like to have:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+----------+
| st1 | st2 | st3 | st4 | TimeStamp           | TimeDiff |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+----------+
| 5   | 5   | 5   | 5   | 2018-07-23 07:50:00 | 66       |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+----------+
| 5   | 5   | 5   | 5   | 2018-07-23 07:39:07 | 492      |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+----------+
```

This might be a difficult way to go about doing this so I am definitely open to other ideas. My end goal is to be able to pull a query and sum the time for state 5 on a daily basis. my problem is getting from the time stamps on stations and their respective states to a time length that I can manipulate and work with. I also might add since there is some variation in these numbers when a station reads state 5 the whole row will be filled with the number 5 unlike the other numbers where the row is filled with different numbers.

If I had the Datediff for each interval I could just narrow it down to state 5 using a where clause so that's why I have the datediff for each time stamp interval in my final table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT

More specific details in the comments below.

Comment: Just to clarify: For an end result, do you want 653 (the number of seconds between the first instance of all State 5 and the 2nd instance)?

Comment: No 653 is not what I am looking for. I made a more detailed table for my end result which shows what I am trying to show. The time elapsed during state 5 instances.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(second, timestamp, lead(timestamp) over (order by timestamp)) as timediff
from t;
```

Comment: I run into the issue after adding a where st1=5 clause that the datediff then gives me the difference between only state 5 instances. Do you know of way for me to get around this? I want to pull the length of individual instances of state 5. Ill update my end result table to represent this now.

Comment: It is giving me the datediff between instances where state = 5 instead of the length of time of the individual state 5 instances.

Comment: @tphasley . . . This is what this question asks for, explicitly with the result set.  I do believe you have asked another question already, which is the right approach.